# Ubuntu input is a problem. When I'm searching for plugins get this as soon as I type (replaced by boxes and can't type numbers)

Tags: ubuntu

That is, I want to search for plugins, but as soon as I enter this (replaced by the box and cannot enter numbers). I use ubuntu21.10. I want to know how to solve this problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKjdF.png)

Comment: If you are facing a problem with the stock version of Ubuntu, please use their bug tracker to report this problem

Comment: I have solved it, just delete it and download it from the official website